Why primary constructor works in my project based on .NET 4.8
From my understanding, primary constructor was introduced in C#12 with .NET 8.
And I use it for dependency injection with AutoFac. And langVersion
is set as Latest Major.
Code looks like this:
public interface IService
{
    Distance GetDistance();
}

public class ExampleController(IService service) : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<Distance> Get()
    {
        return service.GetDistance();
    }
}


Because you are using .net 4.8 with C# 12?

Have a look at the lowered code. If that is compatible with your dotnet version, you should be good.

Certain C# features are just compiler sugar and have been back ported to .NET Framework 4.x projects. But I don't think it is well known and documented very clear in Microsoft Learn.

@001 Yes, I am curious why Microsoft emphasizes that this feature is based on .NET 8.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/primary-constructors

That page states "C# 12 introduces primary constructors", not .NET 8. The "prerequisites" must be referring to compiling, not running the program. I agree that it's somewhat unclear.

I assume you are referring to the line "You need to set up your machine to run .NET 8 or later". I don't know the answer. Maybe .net 8 is bundled with C# 12, and the goal is to get C# 12 installed.

There are two things going on here:

First, the C# compiler uses a process called lowering, where high level features are often first re-written using lower-level constructs, and then the re-written code is what will actually be compiled.
When features are lowered, it isn't something extra done only when needed... it is the way those features were implemented from the beginning. Many newer language features will be written this way as long as it doesn't require runtime support or use types provided by newer .NET releases.

Second, the C# language version and .NET version are separate things, where the language is actually tied more closely to the compiler SDK for what is targeted by the solution or project file than an installed version of .NET. And in fact Visual Studio can use several different SDKs, depending on what you have installed.

Together, you may have a recent version of Visual Studio with support for C# 12, that knows how to lower the code using features from C# 7.3 or earlier, which can then be compiled for .NET 4.8.

Visual Studio with support for C# 12, that knows how to lower the code using features from C# 7.3, is that a thing? Which features that were syntax sugar were backported to C# 7.3?

@IvanPetrov This is not about back-porting. Joel is talking about lowering, which is different. There is also a related link in the answer.

@Fildor yes, all language features that don't rely on newer runtime features/available types can theoretically be supported on .NET Framework 4.8. I was inquiring if there is a list of those features somewhere that's C# 7.3++ or something that include those.

"I strongly concur with the statement: 'The language is ... connected to the compiler SDK, rather than a specific installed version of .NET.'"
So why Microsoft emphasizes that this feature is based on .NET 8.

I am confused about the role of Visual Studio. It's the compiler that lower the code instead of Visual Studio right? What if I use a lower version Visual Studio

@SelmoJack For some users, the compiler ships with the .NET SDK and is invoked via the dotnet command line tool. But others never manually install an SDK, and rely on whatever is included with Visual Studio. Certain versions of Visual Studio, especially older releases, only work up to certain versions of .NET or the SDK.

@SelmoJack I would speculate: because it makes support more complex; a simple "we officially support it on .NET 8+, if it works on earlier (by itself, or with some manual type definitions): great, have fun - if it doesn't: don't use it" policy is pragmatic. Also, the .NET 8 SDK is separate to the .NET 8 runtime

@MarcGravell that's bad imo. It should either be working or not be working. I've found there are some errors that the compiler will issue when it cannot make things work - such as CS8830 Target runtime doesn't support covariant return types in overrides... Will I ALWAYS get an error for the rest of the runtime not-supported cases? Btw google is very silent about CS8830...

Because Microsoft have decided to give you unofficial support for it.
C# language versioning documentation:

The latest C# compiler determines a default language version based on
your project's target framework or frameworks. Visual Studio doesn't
provide a UI to change the value, but you can change it by editing the
csproj file [...] Choosing a language version newer than the default
can cause hard to diagnose compile-time and runtime errors.

for .NET Framework the default version is:

.NET Framework    all     C# 7.3

Since you specified LangVersion to latestMajor:

latestMajor or default - The compiler accepts syntax from the latest
released major version of the compiler.

The compiler that you have is probably part of the .NET 8 SDK which is capable of compiling not only .NET 8, but also .NET Framework. Its latestMajor version is (probably) C# 12.
So when it sees <LangVersion>latestMajor</LangVersion> in csproj it will accept any valid C#12 syntax even for .NET Framework targetting code!
As the other answer mentioned that should be (again that's not officially supported - see above) fine if we just "lower" or have syntax-sugar like features - it will compile to a version of IL that is supported everywhere.
for example with primary constructors:
public class ExampleController(string service)
{
     string GetService() => service;
}

this gets compiled to something that could have been written in .NET Framework without issues:
public class ExampleController
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private string <service>P;

    public ExampleController(string service)
    {
        <service>P = service;
        base..ctor();
    }

    private string GetService()
    {
        return <service>P;
    }
}

However, certain language features like Covariant Return Types that were introduced in .NET 5 and C#9 rely on runtime support to work.
The following code under .NET Framework with LangVersion 9:
public class Food { }
public class Meat : Food { }

public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract Food GetFood();
}

public class Tiger : Animal
{
    public override Meat GetFood() => new Meat();
}

will not work. Luckily we get an error from the compiler:
Error   CS8830  'Tiger.GetFood()': Target runtime doesn't support covariant return types in overrides. Return type must be 'Food' to match overridden member 'Animal.GetFood()'

So, in practice it should be possible to write latest c# version syntax-sugar (pattern matching, primary constructors) and rely on the compiler for errors when we are about to use something the runtime cannot support.
However, Microsoft have decided to not support this officially:

Choosing a language version newer than the default can cause hard to
diagnose compile-time and runtime errors.

